# Algebraic solution to: Do the functions $y=\frac{1}{x}$ and $y=x^3$ ever have the same slope?

Tags: limits

The exercise doesn't specify how it must be answered, so I chose a graphical proof because I couldn't come up with an algebraic one. Sketching the graphs of $y=\frac{1}{x}$ and $y=x^3$, I noticed that $y=x^3$ always has a nonnegative slope, whereas $y=\frac{1}{x}$ always has a negative slope. Therefore these two functions never have the same slope.

However, I'm wondering if there's a algebraic way of showing this. I thought of differentiating each function and setting the values equal, but I think this would only prove that the two functions don't have the same slope at any particular x, and not that they don't have the same slopes anywhere over their domains.

Comment: How is the slope of a function defined?

Comment: the two graphs intersect at the point (1,1) if they intersect here they must have the same slope at that instantaneous point

Comment: @Dom I think you're mistaken.

Comment: @Dom. Not necessarily. Consider "X"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can prove the exact observation you took from your sketch (note that sketch $\ne $ proof), and indeed you are on the right track with differentiation - no wonder if the problem is about slopes.

The derivative of $x\mapsto \frac 1x$ is $-\frac 1{x^2}$ (where $x\ne 0$), hence $<0$ as the square of a nonzero number is strictly positive.

The derivative of $x\mapsto x^3$ is $3x^2$, hence $\ge 0$ (again because squares are nonnegative).

A number $<0$ can never equal a number $\ge 0$.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. Nice and simple Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

By "slope of a function", I assume you mean the slope of the tangent line at a point. ie. the derivative.

So you are looking at $f_1(x) = x^3$ and $f_2(x) = 1/x$, and you want to solve the equation
$$
3x^2 = f_1'(x) = f_2'(x) = \frac{-1}{x^2}
$$
Which gives
$$
x^4 = \frac{-1}{3}
$$
which does not have any real solutions. Is this the kind of proof you were looking for?

Comment: No, I don't think this will do it. This is what I mentioned doing in my question, but (I think) it only shows that the slopes aren't the same at any particular $x$, not that the slopes are never the same (regardless of $x$)

Comment: @yroc Take the equalities at the middle: $3x^2=-\dfrac 1{x^2}$. Now consider them at different points: $3x^2=-\dfrac 1{t^2}$. Conclude.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=x^3$ and $g(x)=x^{-1}$. We have $f'(x)=3x^2$ and $g'(x)=-x^{-2}$, now we do exactly what you said:

$Im(f')\cap Im(g')=\left\{t\in\mathbb{R}|t\geq0 \right\}\cap\left\{t\in\mathbb{R}|t<0 \right\}=\left\{t\in\mathbb{R}|t\geq0\wedge t<0 \right\}=\emptyset$

Comment: Yes, I think you're saying the same thing as Hagen von Eitzen, but using set theory terminology. Thanks.